# How to implement infinite scrolling with Azure DevOps extension Table

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

In our Azure DevOps extension we are using [Advanced table](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/table#advanced-table) from NPM `azure-devops-ui`. But this table has limitations of row count that can display. For example when displaying 1000 rows, then a browser becomes slow and sometimes irresponsible.

We understand that infinite scrolling may be the solution. When scrolling hits the bottom of the page, the next records will be loaded. But there is no example of how to use it with Advanced table.

Should I use some of React library for [infinite scrolling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)? Or there is some mechanism implemented in `azure-devops-ui`? Cannot find it but as I can see, infinite scrolling is realized on Azure DevOps. For example in Pipelines//Runs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didnot develop such an extension. But did you check out the `pageSize` or `scrollable` TableProps?

Comment: pageSize is unfortunately completely undocumented. If I leave pageSize to a default value, Table displays only the first 30 records. So I increased pageSize to 1000 and the Table displays all records but the problem is with the browser's DOM capacity. For this count of records is DOM model too big.

Comment: Another confused user about pageSize: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/issues/48